# Swift if condition fails

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement

Swift `if` statement works fine on all other devices but the iPhone 4S with iOS 9.2.1.

This is the set of code I am using:
I am printing a bool value above, before applying the condition, and it prints 0, but the compiler jumps directly to the `else` part, failing the `if` statement.

```
print(NSNumber.init(value: socketListener!.isConnected)) //prints 0
if socketListener!.isConnected == false { 
    // skipped
} else {
    // executed
}
```

[image]

Comment: why don't you print the value simply as `print(socketListener!.isConnected)`.  Are you sure `socketListener` is not `nil`?

Comment: Yes its not nil.

Comment: Have you check it with `if socketListener!.isConnected {}`

Comment: I had faced this issue earlier.Please try casting the NSNumber to NSInteger or simply taking an Int (not too familiar with objective c). This worked for me. There are some issues with comparison when casting to NSNumber.
Please check and let me know if u need more details

Comment: Have you tried if socketListener!.isConnected simply

Comment: It could also be a bad implementation of `isConnected` getter, which could return a different result when called for the second time. Ideally, start with `let isConnected = socketListener!.isConnected` and then `print(isConnected)` and test `if !isConnected {`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you go the long, but the correct one, by unwrapping your socket listener optional, or you can even go directly with the long unwrapping:

```
guard let isConnected = socketListener.isConnected else { return }

print(NSNumber.init(value: isConnected)) //prints 0
if isConnected == false {
    // Your code
} else {
    // Your code
}
```